# Snowflake UDTF / UDF taking column name as parameter

Tags: sql, function, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions

```
create or replace function get_column_values(column1 string, column2 string, table_name string) 
returns table(table_name varchar, row_count number)
as 
'select distinct column1, column2
from table_name
';
```

Snowflake's documentation says that their function parameter allows input of column names but I can't make it work. The inputs are always interpreted as a string literal and therefore the function above does not work.

Alternatively, if the above is not possible, we can do the same but as a procedure. However, a procedure (returning a table like the function above) cannot be joined with a table, can it?

E.g.

```
select *
from table1
inner join
(CALL procedure_returning_table())
```

There is no specific code to share as this is conceptual - dynamically generate table results that can be used in another query.
Thanks and happy to hear your thoughts on this!

Comment: You can't join to the result set of a stored procedure, but you can dynamically create a SQL statement in a SQL Script stored procedure and return the result set.

Comment: This is what my 'CALL procedure_returning_table()' is doing.
What I want to know is how can I interact with another table based on this result set.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use SQL UDTF with "driving table" by using [TABLE syntax](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/sql/udf-sql-tabular-functions):

```
SELECT *
FROM driving_table AS d
JOIN TABLE(get_column_values(d.column1, d.column2, d.table_name)) AS c;
```

---

The challenge here is that inside UDTF it is not possible to use neither dynamic SQL nor [TABLE/IDENTIFIER](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifier-literal):

```
create or replace function get_column_values(column1 string,
                                             column2 string,
                                             table_name string) 
returns table(table_name string, column2 string)
as 
'select distinct IDENTIFIER(column1), IDENTIFIER(column2)
from TABLE(table_name)
';
```

Comment: are you saying that this is the solution or this is an example that doesn't work?

Comment: @Milleon It is example of what you want to achieve(i.e., use arguments as identifiers and  not strings) and example that this kind of code is NOT supported(as of today) inside UDTF.

Comment: @Milleon [UDTF docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/udf/sql/udf-sql-tabular-functions) says that the body of function must be "sql expression" which excludes usage of Snowflake Scripting block/dynamic SQL.  Usage of TABLE/IDENTIFIER inside ends up with syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

you can try one way, this could work for you

```
select *
from table1
inner join ( select distinct column1, column2
            from table_name )  table_2  on  ....
```

Comment: I don't think you are using a function or any automation that I am trying to get at.